# Is it possible for a function to reference the class on which it's called?

Tags: python, django, model

I have some models defined in Django such as these:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Thread(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And I would like to have an external function that, called inside either of these classes, does something related to the class on which it was called.

For example, a `ListAll()` function that, called inside `Post()`, lists all `Post` objects, but called inside `Thread`, lists all `Thread` objects.

How would I do this? I've seen replies using `__this__` but apparently that references specific class instances, which confuses me a little.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for a mixin, which can be added to any class.

```
class ListAll:
    def list_all(self):
        return self.__class__.objects.all()
```

Add it to the class:

```
class Post(ListAll, models.Model):
     ...
```

And use it:

```
my_post_obj.list_all()
```

I hope this is an example though, as it would be far better to just pass the model class itself into wherever you want to list the objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use functions inside the model and those can be called with class objects

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def listAll(self):
        return self.objects.all() # a function that would return all objects
```

As per comments If you have requirements of using a single function for many models then you can load a model dynamically by its name. I won't say that its recommended or anything but it works perfectly.

```
import importlib
model_module = importlib.import_module('app_name.models.models') 
# remember this example refers to loading a module not its class so if you 
# have a file models.py containing all the models then this should be perfect
model_object = model_module.model_name # now you have loaded the model
data = model_object.objects.all() # apply whatever you want now
```

Comment: But wouldn't that mean having the exact same function on every model? That's what I'm trying to avoid, the repetition.

Comment: if that's so then you have to write a function that takes a model name, import it and apply a filter or query to it. This will include the dynamic loading of the model

Comment: Well that's the point of the question, I don't know how to do that. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Man updated the answer. This answer is based on loading a python module by its name.